# actioncolumn handler not fired when rowediting is activated (extjs)

Tags: javascript, extjs

i have a grid which can be edited using rowediting plugin, but for some reason the update button need to be in the row, like this:

[image]

now, when the row is highlighted, the actioncolumn(the save button) can't be clicked. the handler can't fired. is there any workaround for it?

apparently, this is a known issue, as listed here : 
https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285340-RowEditor-does-not-load-actioncolumn-handler-events-if-active

but i don't know if it's being fixed or not.

i'm using extjs v 4.1

EDIT:

now i able to show button when it's edited, but now the edited row refused to save.

[image]

after clicked save button, the error uccurs:

[image]

now i'm running out of ideas.

Comment: give some fiddle for your code

Comment: Yes, there is a work around. While you defining the configuration of `actioncolumn` there you can place editor as a empty string. like `EDITOR = " "`. This how I am doing. If you paste ur column configuration. I can help you to change accordingly.